# Getting empty swagger UI on a spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger

I am able to get the json response of `localhost:8080/v2/api-docs` but when I try to load swagger-ui on `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` then it shows swagger-ui with no api listed there.

[swagger-ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3ag7.png)

[swagger-json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIATV.png)

Comment: Load swagger-ui with the JS Console open - does it report any errors?

Comment: Edit your question and post your SwaggerConfig class. Also, if you are using Spring Security, verify your Cors configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you can review the following points in your project:

**Check if you have the Spring and Swagger annotations in your Controller class.**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/order")
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 415, message = "Unsupported Media Type"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Unprocessable Entity")
})
public class OrderController {
    // Controller class code.
}
```

**Then, check if your endpoint have the annotations too:**

```
@PostMapping(
        value = "/v1/new",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
)
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Create new Order.",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
)
public ResponseEntity<String> newOrder(
        @RequestHeader(name = "Content-type", defaultValue = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        @NonNull final String contentType,
        @RequestBody @NotNull @Valid OrderDTO orderDTO) {
    // Endpoint code.
}
```

**Swagger Configuration `with` SpringBoot:**

```
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private static final String BASE_PACKAGE = "com.example.api";

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(BASE_PACKAGE))
            .paths(any())
            .build()
            .consumes(getContentType())
            .produces(getContentType())
            .apiInfo(getApiInfo());
    }

    private Set<String> getContentType() {
        final HashSet<String> mediaType = new HashSet<>();
        mediaType.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
        return mediaType;
    }

    private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo(
            //...
        );
    }
}
```

**Swagger Configuration `without` SpringBoot:**

Add: `@Configuration`, `extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and Override the method `addResourceHandlers`, in your SwaggerConfig class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        //...
    }

    private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo(
            //...
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

**Reference:**
[Setting Up Swagger 2 with a Spring REST API](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)

Comment: Yes, I have the same code as you suggested @Juliano. I think the issue is not with the swagger config. I guess my api-docs json is not correct as it is having **json** tag in the json response of the swagger(refer to the swagger-json iamge). 
thanks for reply Juliano

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue, 
Make sure you have enabled your application for Swagger
To do so Use, @EnableSwagger2 annotation as follow:

[image]